# How to disable footer in one of the React JS views without creating new layout?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have about 20 views that use the same layout. Now i need 1 page which does not use footer. First idea i had is to create a new layout but this does not seem like a good way to do this.

LAYOUT

```
const App = () => (
    <div className="full-container">
            <Router history={Router}>
                <Main>
                   <STUFF HERE>
                </Main>
            </Router>
            <Footer/>
        </div>
);
```

VIEW

```
render()
    {
        return (
            <div>
                <h1 className="section-smaller-title">TITLE</h1>
                <STUFFHERE>
                </div>
            </div>

        );
    }
```

FOOTER COMPONENT

```
render() {
        return (
            <footer>
                <img alt="footer logo" className="footer-logo" src="imgsurl"/>
            </footer>
        );
    }
}
```

How can i not show this Footer in that view?
I tried it with

```
document.getElementByClassName(...)
```

But this disabled it everywhere.

What is the standard way of doing this?

Comment: i think, you can put the condition on Footer in App component by checking the route of that view, if that route matches skip the rendering of Footer.

Comment: How is that done? Tried with <Match pattern="/asd" component={Footer}> it said Match is undefined. So it looks at is as component and it isnt my component. Can you point me out to an example.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Conditional Rendering, specifically Inline If with Logical && Operator. Just change your layout to this:

```
const App = () => (
  <div className="full-container">
    <Router history={Router}>
      <Main>
        <STUFF HERE>
      </Main>
    </Router>
    {location.pathname !== “URL path where you don’t want to see footer” && <Footer/>}
  </div>
);
```

More info about Conditional Rendering at https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator Hope it will help.

Comment: This doesn't work perfectly as `location.pathname` is not a React managed state